# Mod Rewrite multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^farbe-([^-]*)/$ ?farbe=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^marke-([^-]*)/$ ?marke=$1 [L]
```

So http://playscout.de/hosen/?marke=diesel/ and http://playscout.de/hosen/?farbe=blau/ becomes http://playscout.de/hosen/marke-diesel/ and http://playscout.de/hosen/farbe-blau/

It works, but i need rules for multiple parameters like http://playscout.de/hosen/marke-diesel/farbe-blau/ so i tryed this for farbe:

```
RewriteRule ^farbe-([^-]*)/$ &farbe=$1 [L]
```

Because from second delimeter it have to be &

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put rule in top, to be executed first:

```
RewriteRule ^marke-([^-]*)/farbe-([^-]*)/$ ?marke=$1&farbe=$2 [L]
```

Comment: For further parameter like page it would be: RewriteRule ^marke-([^-]*)/farbe-([^-]*)/page-([^-]*)/$ ?marke=$1&farbe=$2&page=$3 [L] right?

Comment: yes. i don`t know how to make universal expression for any number of parameters. you can dump part of url with parameters in one parameter and parse it in your page.